# How do I specify a Maven repository for Gitlab in ivy-settings.xml?

Tags: apache-spark, gitlab, ivy

I have no luck with Spark resolving Maven packages from our company Gitlab. My `ivy-settings.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<ivysettings>

  <settings defaultResolver="default"/>

  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml"/>
  <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml"/>

  <credentials host="my.company.com" realm="gitlab-maven" username="Private-Token" passwd="XXXXXXX..." />

  <resolvers>
      <ibiblio name="repo0"
               m2compatible="true"
               useMavenMetadata="true"
               usepoms="true"
               root="https://my.company.com/api/v4/projects/1337/packages/maven"
               pattern="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" />
    <chain name="default" returnFirst="true" checkmodified="true">
      <resolver ref="local" />
      <resolver ref="shared" />
      <resolver ref="public" />
      <resolver ref="repo0" />
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

When I now do something like:

```bash
spark-shell --conf spark.jars.ivySettings=file:///opt/spark/conf/ivy-settings.xml\
            --conf spark.jars.packages=com.company.my:some-artifact:1.2.3
```

I get:

```
:: loading settings :: file = /opt/spark/conf/ivy-settings.xml
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/opt/spark/jars/ivy-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/spark/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/spark/.ivy2/jars
com.company.my#some-artifact added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-3bb84be4-4bc7-41c7-8a74-3d16ffaa584b;1.0
        confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 520ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: com.company.my#some-artifact;1.2.3

        ==== local: tried

          /home/spark/.ivy2/local/com.company.my/some-artifact/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

          -- artifact com.company.my#some-artifact;1.2.3!some-artifact.jar:

          /home/spark/.ivy2/local/com.company.my/some-artifact/1.2.3/jars/some-artifact.jar

        ==== shared: tried

          /home/spark/.ivy2/shared/com.company.my/some-artifact/1.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

          -- artifact com.company.my#some-artifact;1.2.3!some-artifact.jar:

          /home/spark/.ivy2/shared/com.company.my/some-artifact/1.2.3/jars/some-artifact.jar

        ==== public: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/fraunhofer/iwes/some-artifact/1.2.3/some-artifact-1.2.3.pom

          -- artifact com.company.my#some-artifact;1.2.3!some-artifact.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/fraunhofer/iwes/some-artifact/1.2.3/some-artifact-1.2.3.jar

        ==== repo0: tried

          https://my.company.com/api/v4/projects/1337/packages/maven/de/fraunhofer/iwes/some-artifact/1.2.3/some-artifact-1.2.3.pom

          -- artifact com.company.my#some-artifact;1.2.3!some-artifact.jar:

          https://my.company.com/api/v4/projects/1337/packages/maven/de/fraunhofer/iwes/some-artifact/1.2.3/some-artifact-1.2.3.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: com.company.my#some-artifact;1.2.3: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

If I open the printed URLs in my browser, the pom and jar download fine. However, if I use `curl` like so:

```bash
curl -vvv https://my.company.com/api/v4/projects/1337/packages/maven/de/fraunhofer/iwes/some-artifact/1.2.3/some-artifact-1.2.3.pom
```

or

```bash
https://Private-Token:XXXXX...@my.company.com/api/v4/projects/1337/packages/maven/de/fraunhofer/iwes/some-artifact/1.2.3/some-artifact-1.2.3.pom
```

I get 404.

What am I missing?

Comment: If curl is not working, are you sure there is connectivity from spark cluster to your hosted repo?

Comment: I had another go specifying `Private-Token` HTTP header when usung curl, then, it works for curl.

Comment: Hey, what exactly is your Spark cluster setup? Running on local or remote? What's the deploy-mode?
Also, could you try this from the node(s) where spark is running: 
`java -jar download-this-jar/apache-ivy-2.5.0/ivy-2.5.0.jar  -settings path-to-your/ivysettings.xml  -dependency groupId artifactId version -debug`
Note the whitespace b/w groupId, artifactId and version. You can get the ivy jar from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.5.0/ivy-2.5.0.jar)